# Operations on List of Lists to Create New List

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list of lists:

```
[[1,2,3,4], [4,5,6,7],...]
```

and I want to create a new list of lists where each sublist now contains 2 elements (the first element is the product of the first two elements of the first list and the second element is the product of the second two elements):

```
[[1*2, 3*4], [4*5, 6*7]] = [[2,12],[20,42]]
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? You just need to loop over your list

Answer (score 3):

using lambda

```
l=[[1,2,3,4], [4,5,6,7]]

res = list(map(lambda x: [x[0]*x[1], x[2]*x[3]], l))

print(res)
```

output

```
[[2, 12], [20, 42]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply loop over your list and create what you want:

```
result = [[l[0] * l[1], l[2] * l[3]] for l in list_of_lists]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or a more general solution that does not require hardcoding the indexes:

```
lists = [[1, 2 ,3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7]]

print([[a * b for a, b in zip(l[::2], l[1::2])] for l in lists])
# [[2, 12], [20, 42]]
```

This zips together the odd and even indexes in each sublist and multiplies them, at the cost of creating 2 intermediate lists for each sublist.

**Caveats**

- As mentioned above, this will create 2 intermediate lists for each sublist which adds small memory and time overhead.
- This will not work for sublists with an odd number of elements (but it *will* work for lists with any even number of elements)